# Change iFrame atributes and CSS from inside

Tags: html, css, iframe

Is it possible to alter the iframe CSS or atributes from inside the src file?

I want to make a iframe unstyle, so that any1 can copy that code and paste it on their website... something like a feed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't. You should change CSS attributes from the main page.

```
iframe {
  border: 0; /* this will work in the main page, but not in the src file */
}
```

Comment: What if I had a script that did that on my domain, and the other user only had to import the script?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do... maybe if you post some code that would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

All iframe css properties

```
iframe{
margin: 0;
madding: 0;
border: none;
width: value;
height: value;
}
```